Question about lift to Spin$^\mathbb{C}$-group
I'm wondering for what values of $n$ there exists an $m$ such that the usual diagonal inclusion
$$SO(n) \to SO(n+m) \qquad M\mapsto M\oplus I_m$$
lifts to a homomorphism
$$SO(n) \to Spin^\mathbb{C}(n+m)$$
of the $Spin^\mathbb{C}(n+m)$ group. At least if $n = 2$ I can set $m = 0$ since then $SO(2) = U(1)$ and complex representations lift to the Spin$^\mathbb{C}$ group. But for higher values of $n$ I'm not sure if this can be done.

For $n \geq 3$, there is no such $m$.
To see this, first note that the map $\iota : SO(n) \to SO(n+m)$ induces an isomorphism of fundamental groups $\iota_* : \pi_1(SO(n)) \to \pi_1(SO(n+m))$.
Suppose now that $\iota$ were to admit a lift $\tilde{\iota} : SO(n) \to Spin^c(n+m)$, so $p\circ\tilde{\iota} = \iota$ where $p : Spin^c(n+m) \to SO(n+m)$ is the natural map. Then $\iota_* = (p\circ\tilde{\iota})_* = p_*\circ\tilde{\iota}_*$. As $\pi_1(SO(n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\pi_1(Spin^c(n+m)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, the homomorphism $\tilde{\iota}_* : \pi_1(SO(n)) \to \pi_1(Spin^c(n+m))$ is the zero map, and hence so is $\iota_*$. This is a contradiction as $\iota_*$ is an isomorphism (between non-zero groups).

Thank you! Very clean answer. It seems your argument would work also if I replace the the inclusion $\iota: M\to M\oplus I_m$ with a map of the form $M\mapsto M\oplus h(M)$ for some group homomorphism $h: SO(n) \to SO(m)$.

Not quite. If you take $h$ to be the identity, then the map $\iota$ does lift.
